# Connection to WCF service after endpoint change at runtime

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I am creating some authentication form where user must define WCF service IP , user name and password.

Before creating the connection to service, endpoint IP address entered by user is saved to app.config file. See following code:

```
         Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.
                                     OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
         ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceSection = ServiceModelSectionGroup.
                                                      GetSectionGroup(configFile);

        ClientSection clientSection = serviceSection.Client;
        Uri uri = clientSection .Endpoints[0].Address;

        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
        builder.Host = ServerIP;
        clientSection .Endpoints[0].Address = builder.Uri;
        configFile.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

On first connect to WCF everything is ok, that is, if IP is correct it authenticates the user, if not - corresponding message is shown.

But if endpoint IP of service is changed after first connect and client object is recreated, it tries to connect to service using previous IP address, not new one.

I tried to set new endpoint directly to service like this:

```
          ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
          client.Endpoint.Address = new_uri_address;
```

but without success.

I wonder why is this happens and how can I assign new endpoint to WCF client correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

The app.config is read on program first load. your changes won't take effect unless you terminate your application and restart it.
In order to overcome this, you should fully define and configure your wcf client from code.
at least that's the method that worked for me.
i can provide full example if needed

Comment: Thank you for answer. App.config is changed after the application is started but first connection to WCF after this change is OK. The problem occurs when after second change. If the only way is to complete reconfiguration of wcf client, I will try to do it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To be able to connect to a service, a client needs three pieces of information - address, binding and contract. You can try setting these through code and check if the new ip address is used.Look at this solution: [Dynamically set endpoint address in wcf client (with net tcp binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209610/dynamically-set-endpoint-address-in-wcf-client-with-net-tcp-binding)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers again. I have recreated the wcf client by defining binding and endpoint and it worked.

```
    Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.
                                 OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceSection = ServiceModelSectionGroup.
                                                  GetSectionGroup(configFile);

    ClientSection clientSection = serviceSection.Client;

    System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding bind = new BasicHttpBinding(clientSection .Endpoints[0].BindingConfiguration);
    EndpointAddress newEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(clientSection .Endpoints[0].Address);

    my_service = new TCCSServiceClient(bind, newEndpoint);
```