# Multiple Endpoints for WCF Client

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have generated a webservice client (Service Reference) from a wsdl file provided by a web service. This webservice runs on 2 (or more) machines. What I like to do is to call from a single client (a windows service) both machines in a round robin fashion. If one of the webservices is offline the client should automatically choose the other instance.

The app.config file is very simple:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyServicePortBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://server:8080/myservice/services" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="MyServicePortBinding" contract="Service.MyService"
            name="MyServicePort1"  />
    </client>      
</system.serviceModel>
```

What I tried is to add a second endpoint to the configuration. This does fail with the exception: `System.InvalidOperationException: An endpoint configuration section for contract 'Service.MyService' could not be loaded because more than one endpoint configuration for that contract was found. Please indicate the preferred endpoint configuration section by name.`

Do you have any ideas how to set up a simple wcf loadbalancing mechanism on the client side?

Cheers

Fabian

Edit: This is not a duplicate to the linked question. The question here is how to implement a client based loadbalancing, not what happens if I put in 2 endpoints. This was only what I came up with.

Comment: Load balancing is normally done on the server not the client.

Comment: I agree, but it is not possible for me to use a loadbalancer on the server. I could only install a loadbalancer on one server which would be a single point of failure.

Comment: You may find relief using dynamic endpoints, e.g. placing hostname's in app.config and doing something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209610/dynamically-set-endpoint-address-in-wcf-client-with-net-tcp-binding)

Comment: The solution in @RamblinRose comment was to dynamically change the url in my own code. I thought more of [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/778575/WCF-Routing-Service-Part-III-Failover-Load-Balanci), but without the need of an extra project for the virtual endpoint/router.